# How to recreate a jar file after hacking the original one?

Tags: java, android

This maybe a noob question but please help me.
I found a library called Graphview for android and I would like to customize a bit and use it in my project. I know .jar is a zip file so after I extracted it I saw 2 folders, one contains some .class files and .java files, My question is, do I just need to change the codes I want in .java files? How about those .class files? And How do I put all the changed files back to recreate a new .jar file so I can use it in my project?

Here is the library from Github :**https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/downloads**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would

- fork the original git library.
- modify it.
- build it.
- consider providing your improvement to the original build.

I wouldn't try hacking the existing library even though you can do this if you really have to (because you have no access to the original build)

Comment: I am not trying to hack it, just customize it, because I need to change some color of that graph library so that my app looks better. THerefore it is not a good contribution to the original build.

Comment: @qwrqwr I imagine other people want their apps to look better too. ;) In any case, I would build from the original where possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can just clone the original project, make your changes there, and then jar the changed project.

Comment: I fork and download the project from Github and import it to my Eclipse, but there is no gen folder and no project properties, am I missing something?

Comment: Here are some instructions on how to export to a Jar with Eclipse
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-jar-file-in-java-eclipse/